# Trusty on Lenovo IdeaTab Miix2

Tags: 14.04, windows-8, lenovo, tablet

I would like to be able to install Trusty on this Windows tablet and replace Windows completely. The only thing that I've been able to find on it is that Secure Boot has to be disabled (which I figured out), EFI support is not available on newer versions of Ubuntu and that it is extremely difficult if not impossible to get it running on devices like mine. ([http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00F2ENTYI/ref=oh_details_o04_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00F2ENTYI))

Can anyone please shed some light on this situation for me? I'm about to go crazy with Windows 8!